# Failing to retrieve all images from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a simple webpage where I want to display a few images that are located on my computer @ *C:\xampp\htdocs\website\upload*. I have stored their (relative) paths into the MySQL database, like this: *website/upload/filename.extension*.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO `photos` (`photoid`, `photopath`, `photoname`, `photoyear`) 
VALUES ('20', 'website/upload/Putin.jpg', 'Putin', '2017');
```

The PHP code that's supposed to retrieve them is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

while($photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<img src="'. $photo['photopath'] .'" alt="'.$photo['photoname'].'" height:"100" width="100"> <br />';
}
```

However, it only returns one picture and completely ignores the others, the result being [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wa7.png). And if I remove that particular picture from my database, it displays [none of the others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oOlm.png), although their location and filetype coincide.

What can I do so that all the images are displayed successfully?
Thank you!

Comment: Right-click on the images with errors and check whether the links are ok. If there's a 404 for images then the problem is with the link that you have stored.

Comment: That was it. The paths stored in the database should've been simply _upload/filename.ext_ (no _website/_). Thanks! I was worried that there was something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the images with errors and open Inspect Element, check whether the links are ok. If there's a 404 for images then the problem is with the link that you have stored.